# Variable inside model doesn't show correct value when accessing it

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, prism

I'm trying to check on on a boolean whether it's true or false. When i'm debugging and hovering over my object in the breakpoint, i see the right value. But when i'm hovering over the variabel that im accessing it shows the wrong value.

Here it's shown correctly, as true

[image: Model]

And here it's suddenly false

[image: Variabel]

Here's how my object looks like

```
[DataContract]
public class CompanyTypeCode : RealmObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    [DataMember(Name = "speciesId")]
    public long SpeciesId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "useTypeCode")]
    public long UseTypeCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "mandatoryHerdSizes")]
    public bool MandatoryHerdSizes { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "companyTypeText")]
    public string CompanyTypeText { get; set; } 

    [DataMember(Name = "mandatoryPractice")]
    public bool MandatoryPractice { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this could be just some weird debugger artifact - do you see the same results if you use `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: Side note: `OnPropertyChanged` doesn't make sense if it isn't called...

Answer (score 0):

So it seems, as [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason)
wrote, this is a debugger issue. When i wrote the variables to the console, they had the right values. Thx!